# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, security, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to customize `UserDetailsService`, my class is:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
//    @Transactional
    public UserPrincipal loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        UserPrincipal principal = userRepository.getByUsername(username);
        // make sure the authorities and password are loaded
        principal.getAuthorities().size();
        principal.getPassword();
        return principal;
    }
}
```

and my `UserPrincipal` is:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer, Cloneable {
...
    private Set<UserAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "UserPrincipal_Authority", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "UserId", referencedColumnName = "UserId")
    })
    public Set<UserAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        return this.authorities;
    }
...
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <import resource="securityConfig.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test"/>

    <!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.security"/>
        <!-- Set share cache mode -->
        <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
        <!-- Set validation mode -->
        <property name="validationMode" value="NONE"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!--
      Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the
      repository interfaces
    -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.security"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

When the `@Transactional` is commented out I get

> Reason: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: `com.security.UserPrincipal.authorities`, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

which makes sense. When I add the `@Transactional` I get this error:

> No qualifying bean of type [`com.security.UserService`] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

The code used to work, I can't figure out what I have changed that broke the code.

This is the full exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityController' defined in file [C:\Users\nfallah\Documents\workspace-intelliJ\Spring-Hybrid-Config - MVC - CSR - Secure - DB\target\spring-hybrid-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\security\SecurityController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.security.UserService]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.security.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.security.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:742) ~[ConstructorResolver.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) ~[ConstructorResolver.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [HttpServletBean.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4922) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1588) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.security.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:806) ~[ConstructorResolver.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:734) ~[ConstructorResolver.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: That is not a compile error.

Comment: Post your transactional configuration.

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace. When you pick 1 or 2 lines and put here you are leaving the helpful information behind.

Comment: Check AOP explanation in my answer to unrelated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012070/spring-managed-transaction-commits-where-it-shouldnt/25013532#25013532 . If you are autowiring based on the target class and you are using _JDK proxy based_ AOP, it won't work. **You should autowire on interface** or don't use AOP in this case (and use `TransactionTemplate` instead) or use CGLIB (_proxy-target-class_) based AOP.

Comment: For a quick fix you might try adding this annotation to your `UserService`: `@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added proxy-target-class="true" to <tx:annotation-driven/> and it's fixed

Comment: @Navid So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `@Transactional` Spring makes a proxy of `UserService` and, unless you tell it otherwise, Spring defaults to using interface-based proxies (with the dynamic proxy API).

Thus the type that you should rather depend on is `UserDetailsService` since that is the interface type and thus the type of the bean that is created.

The reason it prefers to use the interface is that it's a bit more lightweight than using a CGLIB approach (which it uses when you set the `proxy-target-class=true`).